# Postgresql return table result

Tags: postgresql

I want to return table. But Here is the error I am getting. How can I solve this one to return a table?

> ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
>   DETAIL:  Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
>   CONTEXT:  SQL function "delete"
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return record
>   SQL state: 42P13"

```
 CREATE TABLE myTable (
 id serial  NOT NULL,
 name varchar(255) default NULL,
 surname varchar(255) default NULL,
 phone varchar(100) default NULL,
 constraint p_key primary key(id)
) ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete(name text,surname text)
RETURNS table(id int, name text, surname text, phone text) AS
$$
DELETE FROM myTable where name=$1 and surname=$2;   
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Add `RETURNING` to the query: `DELETE FROM myTable where name=$1 and surname=$2 RETURNING *;` But why do you need a function for such a trivial action?

Comment: thanks for answer. your answer is right. I learn pgsql.